# How to change key-binding for VS2013 quick replace and quick replace all?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, key-bindings

I'm wondering how to setup key-binding for quick search and quick replace in VisualStudio 2013.

Currently "Replace next" is binded to ALT+R and "Replace all to ALT+A. What is interesting, there is no such binding in Environment->Keyboard settings:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/mFIhJqV.png]

There is only "SwitchToQuickReplace" but nothing for ReplaceNext and ReplaceAll. Only item is "Edit.Replace" but changing this binding doesn't affect quick-replace binding. Also if I tried to bind ALT+R or ALT+A to another command, there is no conflict message:

[image]

Does this means that QuickFind and QuickReplace has these shortcuts hard-coded and there is no way how to change it?

Comment: Hi Ludek, have you found the answer to your problem?  The Alt+A shorcut collides with a national character in my mother language and I can't use it.  In VS2010 you could just hit enter and all changes were made to the selected text.  In both VS2013 and VS2015 there is a horrible Alt+A shortcut which I can't change.

Comment: Unfortunately no. There is no way how to use or simulate old VS2010 workflow. It's very annoying every-time I need to replace all.

Comment: VS2017 has just been published and still the same problem.  Oh, those Americans, they assume English is the only language in the world...